# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong right now.  I think I'm mentally exhausted, because I'm utterly clueless.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
if(empty($this->updates) || !is_array($this->updates))
    return null;

foreach($this->updates as $update)
```

This is failing.  HOWEVER, if I do a print_r($this->updates) before the foreach (and after), it works perfectly fine.  Why is it that when I try to use it in a foreach it pretends the array doesn't exist?

Sample print_r($this->updates):

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
    (
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => test
    ) 
    [1] = Array
    (
       [id] => 2 
       [name] => rawr
    )
)
```

Comment: This error usually occurs if you try passing any thing *other than* an array into a `foreach`. What does your `print_r` return ?

Comment: can we see the result of `print_r`?

Comment: Can you tell use the result of var_dump($this->updates) ? Plus, you should add if(!isset($this->updates) || empty($this->updates))

Comment: @Chouchenos that still does not check if it is an array.

Comment: My code is on a classified machine, but I can give you a simple mockup of what updates contains.  I assure you, it's an array.

Comment: Array
    (
        [0] = Array
        (
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => test
        ) 
        [1] = Array
        (
           [id] => 2 
           [name] => rawr
        )
    )

Comment: @Russell Dias : Indeed. if(!is_array($this->updates) || empty($this->updates)) is better. Thanks for the correction ;)

Comment: That still doesn't impact the problem.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't tell what `$this->updates` is, I can simply assume it's not an array. Here, you have two options :

1- Replace `empty()` with `!is_array()` to check if `$this->updates` is valid or not. If it's empty, it doesn't matter, the `foreach` will simply do nothing...

```
if(!is_array($this->updates))
    return null;

foreach($this->updates as $update)
```

Or if the `foreach` is not the only processing you do :

```
if(empty($this->updates) || !in_array($this->updates))
    return null;

foreach($this->updates as $update)
```

2- Force `$this->updates` to be an array

```
if(empty($this->updates))
    return null;

foreach((array) $this->updates as $update)
```

Comment: $this-updates is already an array.  I posted the results of a print_r in the original question.

Comment: @Atrox, is this piece of code executed twice? Maybe the first pass works, but fails on the second one (or vice-versa)? Because there is NO way that `foreach` fail if `$this->updates` is **always** indeed an array

Comment: It's executed about 90 times on one page, and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  If I use print_r before the foreach, it works 100% of the time.

Comment: the execution of a single PHP request is single threaded, this is not likely or even possible. ... have you tried what I'm suggesting? Particularly the second suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$this->updates` is not empty but its not an array. You can use the `is_array` test before you use it in `foreach`:

```
if(is_array($this->update)) {
  foreach($this->updates as $update) {
  .....
 }
}
```

Comment: $this-updates definitely has entries in it.  For the particular piece of code I'm working on, there are 27 arrays within updates.  I posted the results of an example print_r in the original question.